# Security Flaw in all "logging by" system - phishing opportunity

Tags: logging, phishing

We all face such popups.

[image: Phishing opportunity]

How can you assure that it's NOT phishing, if It's not in the browser.

UIWebView (View that displays this logging view) is controlled by application we really don't even know if this is secured connection!

Is it true that developer could easily turned those logging windows into phishing or I'm missing something ?

The same thing with mobile applications that display (supposedly) UIWebView instead redirect to browser.

Comment: I would enable 2-factor auth if you haven't already. Does right clicking bring up a menu?

Comment: Only "reload" option shows when right clicking.